# How should I add a collapsible sidebar in gtk4?

Tags: user-interface, gtk, sidebar

The few options that I found have to do with using the following:

```
<child>
      <object class="GtkBox" id="content_box">
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkSearchBar" id="searchbar">
            <child>
              <object class="GtkSearchEntry" id="searchentry">
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkBox" id="hbox">
            <child>
              <object class="GtkRevealer" id="sidebar">
                <property name="transition-type">slide-right</property>
                <child>
                 <object class="GtkScrolledWindow" id="sidebar-sw">
                   <property name="hscrollbar-policy">never</property>
                   <child>
                     <object class="GtkListBox" id="words">
                       <property name="selection-mode">none</property>
                     </object>
                   </child>
                 </object>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkStack" id="stack">
                <property name="transition-duration">500</property>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
```

On the GTK website itself, there is an option called `GtkStackSidebar`, but it appears to be quite restrictive in what children nodes can be visible.

How should I create a sidebar that I can click to reveal and have elements that I can populate from the rest of the code?